# How do I post simple JSON data with a file upload?

Tags: c#, typescript, servicestack

I'm trying to set up a file upload request in a ServiceStack TypeScript client that also includes the month for which the file is relevant. How do I set up the request so that both come through to the server?

I've tried various changes, including manually changing headers to try to force Content-Type to be application/json, which didn't work (but I suspect would break the file upload even if it did).

Client-side API:

```js
export const serviceApi = {
    importData: (month: string, file: File) => {
        var client = new JsonServiceClient("");
        var request = new DTOs.ImportData();

        // At this point, the month has a value
        request.month = month.replace('/', '-').trim();

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('description', file.name);
        formData.append('type', 'file');
        formData.append('file', file);

        const promise = client.postBody(request, formData);
        return from(promise);
    },
};
```

DTO definition:

```cs
[Route("/api/data/import/{Month}", "POST")]
public class ImportData : IReturn<ImportDataResponse>
{
    public string Month { get; set; }
}

public class ImportDataResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Server-side API:

```cs
[Authenticate]
public object Post(ImportData request)
{
    if (Request.Files == null || Request.Files.Length <= 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("No import file was received by the server");
    }

    // This is always coming through as null
    if (request.Month == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("No month was received by the server");
    }

    var file = (HttpFile)Request.Files[0];
    var month = request.Month.Replace('-', '/');

    ImportData(month, file);

    return new ImportDataResponse();
}
```

I can see that the file is coming through correctly on the server side, and I can see an HTTP request going through with the month set in the query string parameters as "07-2019", but when I break in the server-side API function, the month property of the request is null.

Update, here are the HTTP Request/Response headers:

Request Headers

```
POST /json/reply/ImportData?month=07-2019 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:40016
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 7366169
Origin: http://localhost:40016
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryI8CWlbw4tP80PkpZ
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:40016/data
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.673673009.1532913806; ASP.NET_SessionId=gtwdk3wsvdn0yulhxyblod3g; __utmc=111872281; __utmz=111872281.1533684260.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ss-opt=perm; __utma=111872281.673673009.1532913806.1550789161.1550794391.20; _gid=GA1.1.893581387.1558389301; ss-id=kfq4G0GYb3WldSdCaRyJ; ss-pid=aZ400sqM4n3TQgNVnHS2
```

Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Exception
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/5.10 NET45 Win32NT/.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcVEZTXFNvdXJjZVxNZWRpc2VuXFdlYnNpdGVzXE9OaWlDU1xNYWluXFNvdXJjZVxPbmlpY3NSZWFjdC1QYXltZW50c1xPbmlpY3NSZWFjdFxPbmlpY3NSZWFjdFxqc29uXHJlcGx5XEltcG9ydE1CU0NvZGVz?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 21 May 2019 21:49:03 GMT
Content-Length: 605
```

Query String Parameters

```
month=07-2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to upload a file using [JavaScript's fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) directly, e.g:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('description', file.name);
formData.append('type', 'file');
formData.append('file', file);

fetch('/api/data/import/07-2019', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
});
```

Otherwise if you want to use ServiceStack's [TypeScript JsonServiceClient](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference#typescript-serviceclient) you would need to use the API that lets you post the Request DTO with a separate request body, e.g:

```
formData.append('month', '07-2019');
client.postBody(new ImportData(), formData);
```

Comment: I'm happy to use fetch, but for consistency with my other APIs, I'd like to try to make the JsonServiceClient work. Your second piece of code looks a lot like mine (with the request just declared in-line instead of in a variable). Can you elaborate on what the difference is?

Comment: @Mortdestro There's no difference, as of [v5.5 all TypeScript DTOs support partial constructors](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.5#partial-constructors) which is just a more succinct way of populating DTOs.

Comment: If there's no difference, then that method seems not to be working. I will give fetch a try and see if that fixes it. Thank you!

Comment: Fetch did work, and I'm happy to use it, but do you have any idea why the JsonServiceClient method didn't work?

Comment: Spoke too soon! The request came back as successful, but nothing happened server-side. It won't even hit the breakpoint in the API function

Comment: @Mortdestro Can you try my updated answer of populating the property in the formData? You're going to have to update your question with the raw HTTP Request/Response headers to be able to see what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, that's what dprogramz also suggested, and it looks like it works. I will throw in the headers to see if it can be resolved with JsonServiceClient though.

Comment: I have added the headers to the question

Comment: @Mortdestro it's returning a 500 error response, but unfortunately doesn't say why. I added a [test example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/371de954eca86466d4febf1433c81cadf75770ed), which worked except the FormData Request DTO wasn't also populated with queryString params which is now being populated from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/dced03ac1941480e55fc46990ba8d5fe1ac4ba85). So this works with [latest v5.5.1 on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget). FYI you don't need to replace `/` when sending as queryString or FormData.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the month should be part of the request header, that's kinda unorthodox. It should be part of the form data.

If you did:

```
  formData.append('Month', month.replace('/', '-').trim());
```

client side, then request.Month or request.content.Month should work, depending on how the request object is handled in your instance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm happy to do it this way if it's the only way of getting the data, but across all of my service APIs, I've been utilizing ServiceStack's auto-generated types to keep requests consistent between client- and server-side. I believe this normally goes through as a request payload, but this time it seems to be putting it in the query string, which I find odd.

Comment: @Mortdestro ah, I understand. most webdevs I know would say that html headers are only to be used for transport information, not semantics. Also, keep in mind, custom headers can cause problems based on client side implementation as well, for instance, some proxies and firewalls will inspect and rewrite headers, mobile service providers have a history of modifying headers as well, especially in the UK

Comment: That's good to know. I don't believe I'm creating any custom headers at the moment (I did try it at one point, but currently I am relying on ServiceStack to generate the HTTP request for me). I just feel a bit crazy here, it looks like I'm setting it up correctly, and yet the server isn't getting my data.

Comment: oh sorry, I read the request object wrong and though it was the header, not the URI.

Comment: Well, your suggestion did solve my problem. It's not my ideal solution, but it looks like either there's some kind of bug with JsonServiceClient with these kinds of requests, this kind of request isn't supposed to be made, or I'm missing something somewhere else in the code that's causing the request to be wonky. The other answerer just suggested the same thing, so I suppose this is the best way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mortdestro glad my suggestion helped!